# How to make grep stop at first match on a line?

Tags: grep

Well, I have a file test.txt

```
#test.txt
odsdsdoddf112 test1_for_grep
dad23392eeedJ test2 for grep
Hello World test
garbage
```

I want to extract strings which have got a space after them. I used following expression and it worked

```
grep -o  [[:alnum:]]*.[[:blank:]]  test.txt
```

Its output is

```
odsdsdoddf112
dad23392eeedJ 
test2 
for    
Hello 
World
```

But problem is grep prints all the strings that have got space after them, where as I want it to stop after first match on a line and then proceed to second line.

Which expression should I use here, in order to make it stop after first match and move to next line?

This problem may be solved with gawk or some other tool, but I will appreciate a solution which uses grep only.

**Edit**
I using GNU grep 2.5.1 on a Linux system, if that is relevant.

**Edit**

With the help of the answers given below, I tried my luck with

```
grep  -o   ^[[:alnum:]]*  test.txt
grep  -Eo  ^[[:alnum:]]+  test.txt
```

and both gave me correct answers.

Now what surprises me is that I tried using

```
grep -Eo "^[[:alnum:]]+[[:blank:]]" test.txt
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495229/how-to-make-grep-stop-at-first-match-on-a-line/1495253#1495253) but didn't get the correct answer. 
Here is the output on my terminal

```
odsdsdoddf112
dad23392eeedJ 
test2 
for    
Hello 
World
```

But comments from RichieHindle and Adrian Pronk, shows that they got correct output on their systems. Anyone with some idea that why I too am not getting the same result on my system. Any idea? Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**

Well, it seems that grep 2.5.1 has some bug because of which my output wasn't correct. I installed grep 2.5.4, now it is working correctly. Please see [this link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/why-this-grep-command-with-regular-expressions-not-working-on-my-system-758692/) for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're sure you have no leading whitespace, add a `^` to match only at the start of a line, and change the `*` to a `+` to match only when you have one or more alphanumeric characters.  (That means adding `-E` to use extended regular expressions).

```
grep -Eo "^[[:alnum:]]+[[:blank:]]" test.txt
```

(I also removed the `.` from the middle; I'm not sure what that was doing there?)

Comment: I copied your command to my terminal but got the exactly same result.

Comment: @andrew-dufresne: Is there something weird about your text file? Try `od -c test.txt` Does that show the characters you were expecting to see?

Comment: @RichieHindle : Thanks for your prompt responses, I really appreciate it. I executed the command and got the same characters as in the test.txt

Comment: I tried this using GNU grep 2.5.3 and it produces the output I expected:  odsdsdoddf112 <NEWLINE>dad23392eeedJ <NEWLINE>Hello <NEWLINE>

Comment: @RichieHindle and @Adrian Pronk  : This time I tried grep -o ^[[:alnum:]]* test.txt and it worked correctly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RichieHindle and @Adrian Pronk : With grep 2.5.4, your expression worked. grep 2.5.1 has some bug in it. Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question how to make grep stop after first match. grep will continue to filter all input without stopping and can potentially match something from garbage...

Answer (score 2):

As the questioner discovered, this is a [bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=11579) in versions of GNU grep prior to 2.5.3.  The bug allows a caret to match after the end of a previous match, not just at beginning of line.

This bug is still present in other versions of grep, for instance in Mac OS X 10.9.4.

There isn't a universal workaround, but in the some examples, like non-spaces followed by a space, you can often get the desired behavior by leaving off the delimiter.  That is, search for `'[^ ]*'` rather than `'[^ ]* '`.

Comment: Posting this as an answer so that this information is easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oe "^[^ ]* " test.txt
```

Comment: I pasted your command and got the same result as I have got earlier.

Comment: You are right. My grep version 2.5.1 was the culprit. Installed 2.5.4 and your expression worked. Thanks a lot BryanH. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to extract all meaningful input before garbage and actually stop on first match then `-B NUM, --before-context=NUM` option may be useful to "print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines".

Example:

```
grep --before-context=999999 "Hello World test"
```