# How to get `grep -o` to output only the first match on a line?

Tags: grep

Using *GNU* `grep`:

```
echo zabczabc | egrep -o 'a{1}'
a
a
```

Here the goal was to output only the *first* "a", but not the second.  Adding `-m 1` has no effect.

Without using a pipe to any util, (i.e. `| tail -1`), does *GNU* `grep` alone offer any way to output only the *first*, (or better yet the *n*th), match from one line?

*Perl* style `grep -P` answers are OK.  Or, if the above is known to be, or is provably, impossible, that would also be an answer.

---

Note:  this is not a duplicate of the 2009 question [How to make grep stop at first match on a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495229/how-to-make-grep-stop-at-first-match-on-a-line), since in that answer:

1. The OP settled for a non-general answer.
2. There seemed to some sort of `grep` version related bugs involved.

Comment: Append `| grep -m 1 .`.

Comment: @Cyrus: Thanks.  The Q is unclear, I meant no piping to any other util,  including `grep`.   Have now reworded Q to remove that loophole.

Comment: With GNU grep? `grep -Po '^.*?\Ka{1}(?=.*$)'`

Comment: @Cyrus, Wow that's gnarly.  Please post it as an answer, as it certainly qualifies...

Comment: BTW, the reason `-m 1` has no effect is that even though it is described as "stop after `n` matches," it actually means "stop after searching the first `n` matching lines." Since you have multiple matches on the same line, you get all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest with GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '^.*?\Ka{1}(?=.*)'
```